# Fontspec says filename includes a [ but it doesn't

Tags: fonts, files

Using `xelatex` to process this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf}
\begin{document}
 Some text.
\end{document}
```

results in a reported error

```
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf]/OT', contains `['
```

I use the Ubuntu OS. I purchased the Linotype Optima fonts and put them in directory `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/Linotype/Optima/OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf` etc. (as recommended by Ubuntu). I ran `fc-cache` and then `fc-list` which reported all the Optima fonts I had installed.

The filenames of the fonts do not include any `[` or `]` so why the error message?

Comment: does `\setmainfont{OptimaLTStd-Medium}` work?

Comment: I have only the regular weight, but its behavior suggests that `\setmainfont{Optima LT Std Medium}` would work. Can you try that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\setmainfont{OptimaLTStd-Medium}` works. I included the `.otf` extension following Example 1 in the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: @Thérèse `\setmainfont{Optima LT Std Medium}` worked as did `\setmainfont{Optim LT Std Medium Italic}` for an italic style.

Comment: it's a natter of practising the dark arts to see which one works. if I remember correctly if you do `{OptimaLTStd-Medium}` then xetx will ask fontconfig for a file with that internal font name, but if you use `{OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf` then xetex will ask kpathsea to do a tex filename search for a font file with that name, so I think in your case fc-list is working but not the tex kpathse setup

Comment: The italic should be found automatically, but if it’s not, `\setmainfont{Optima LT Std Medium}[ItalicFont={* Italic}]` will probably work.

Comment: @Thérèse That worked. I must go away and try and study/practice more.

Answer (score 5):

I think it means that xetex didn't find the fonts then it's falling back on the classic tex make tfm scripts to try to make a font which then give a spurious error over the xetex font name convention.

I get the error about a bracket in the filename, but only after errors from fontspec saying it can not find the font (not surprising in my case as I don't have it)

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "OptimaLTStd-Medium" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.3 \setmainfont{OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf}

? 
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf]/OT', contains '['
! Font TU/OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf(0)/m/n/10=[OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf]/OT at 10.0p
t not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.3 \setmainfont{OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf}

?
```

If you get the `kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename \`[`OptimaLTStd-Medium.otf]/OT', contains '['` without the `!!!!!!!!!` error first from fontspec then it's a different issue and I'll probably delete this.

Comment: The error message comes from `kpathsea:make_tex` before `fontspec` says it can't find the file. Note that the two comments to my question both solved my problem, though in different ways. Any chance that someone will produce a `fontspec` guide for simple minded folk (apologies to Will Robertson)?

Comment: @PeterWilson actually that's what I'd expect (I think I will edit the wording in my answer) classically if the tfm font metrics are not available before giving the missing font error tex runs maketextfm to try to make some tfms from metafont sources, so running makexxx before getting the error is expected but of course the script fails completely when given a xetex font spec in square brackets.

Comment: If you edit your answer to take into account the several comments and my answers then I'm pretty sure that I will accept it.